# Knockout.js binding does not work while working with collections

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I'm a beginner to Knockoutjs. While working with collections it seems to me binding does not work (text is shown but it's not updated after value updating). As example the following code:

```
<h2>People</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <div>          
            <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has <span data-bind='text: children().length'>&nbsp;</span> children:
            <a href='#' data-bind='click: addChild '>Add child</a>
            <span class='renderTime' data-bind='visible: $root.showRenderTimes'>
                (person rendered at <span data-bind='text: new Date().getSeconds()' > </span>)
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: children">
            <li>
              <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data">
                <span data-bind="text: $data"> </span>
                <span class='renderTime' data-bind='visible: $root.showRenderTimes'>
                    (child rendered at <span data-bind='text: new Date().getSeconds()' > </span>)
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<label><input data-bind='checked: showRenderTimes' type='checkbox' /> Show render times</label>
```

It's a code from example on the official Knockout.js site
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html
 The source js code is this:

```
// Define a "Person" class that tracks its own name and children, and has a method to add a new child
var Person = function(name, children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children); 
    this.addChild = function() {
        this.children.push("New child");
    }.bind(this);
} 
// The view model is an abstract description of the state of the UI, but without any knowledge of the UI technology (HTML)
var viewModel = {
    people: [
        new Person("Annabelle", ["Arnie", "Anders", "Apple"]),
        new Person("Bertie", ["Boutros-Boutros", "Brianna", "Barbie", "Bee-bop"]),
        new Person("Charles", ["Cayenne", "Cleopatra"])
    ],
    showRenderTimes: ko.observable(false)
}; 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I've just made one change - added

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data">
```

Everything is fine displayed. But text is not updated after value changing. It seems that binding does not work. I faced with the same problem in a real project as well. It is confused me. What's going wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you took isn't particularly well suited to make a two-way binding work, but let's try anyways. Note that `children` is an observable `array` (so additions/removals are noticed) but the items inside it are plain strings, *not* observables. For a two-way binding to work you'd need that.

In addition, a "child" is just a plain string, further complicating things.

I suggest editing the example a bit to make sure children are mapped to `new Person(...)` instances and have their `name` property be an `ko.observable(...)`. The `addChild` function should then also create `new Person(...)` instances.

See this example:

```js
// Define a "Person" class that tracks its own name and children, and has a method to add a new child
var Person = function(name, children) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children.map(c => new Person(c, []))); 
    this.addChild = function() {
        this.children.push(new Person("New child", []));
    }.bind(this);
} 
// The view model is an abstract description of the state of the UI, but without any knowledge of the UI technology (HTML)
var viewModel = {
    people: [
        new Person("Annabelle", ["Arnie", "Anders", "Apple"]),
        new Person("Bertie", ["Boutros-Boutros", "Brianna", "Barbie", "Bee-bop"]),
        new Person("Charles", ["Cayenne", "Cleopatra"])
    ],
    showRenderTimes: ko.observable(false)
}; 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>People</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <div>          
            <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has <span data-bind='text: children().length'>&nbsp;</span> children:
            <a href='#' data-bind='click: addChild '>Add child</a>
            <span class='renderTime' data-bind='visible: $root.showRenderTimes'>
                (person rendered at <span data-bind='text: new Date().getSeconds()' > </span>)
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: children">
            <li>
              <input type="text" data-bind="value: name">
                <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
                <span class='renderTime' data-bind='visible: $root.showRenderTimes'>
                    (child rendered at <span data-bind='text: new Date().getSeconds()' > </span>)
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<label><input data-bind='checked: showRenderTimes' type='checkbox' /> Show render times</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works for me now. But one more question appeared concerning this topic. While pushining to children array you create new object of Person. But what would be if Person class does not describe an object in children array? In this case should I make another class constructor i.e. Child and push new Child (..) to children array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a design question, not a technical question (as far as I understand it). Up to you. (I'd only create a seperate class if instances would have different properties, which is typically not the case: a Child of someone can have children of his/her own, and thus is IMO usually a Person...)

Comment: I got it. Thank you.